# why my actionbar is not display in fragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

why my actionbar is not display in fragment?

I have add search.xml in menu folder, and this is search.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Message"/>

</menu>
```

in my homefragment, I have add this code.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.HomeFragment">
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:title="IFUNPOT" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:id="@+id/recy_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but I can see the actionbar, but why cannot display search and message icon?

Comment: Did you call setHasOptionsMenu(true); ?

Answer (score 0):

try to put this line in parent layout

```
android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
```

> like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.HomeFragment">
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:title="IFUNPOT" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:id="@+id/recy_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragment add:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    //....
}
```

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)):

> The **`setHasOptionsMenu`** method reports that this fragment would like to participate in populating the options menu by receiving a call to `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)` and related methods.